# Magento 2: Getting unknown category

Tags: magento2, category, collection, category-listing

I am trying to get a level 2 category list. I got all level 2 categories but I am also getting 2 unknown categories which are not in backend. This is weird.
Here is my code

```
public function getShopCategories()
{
    $objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

    $categories = $categoryFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>2));

    return $categories;
}
```

I reindexed and checked for different store views but not getting these categories.

Comment: Have you checked in the database is `unknown` category is present?

Comment: Use the below query to get all categories.

Comment: SELECT `e`.*,
       IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`
FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '41')
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '41')

Comment: thank you, it worked @ChiragPatel

Comment: Should I post this comment as an answer?

Comment: @ChiragPatel yess

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation answer :) +1 for your appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check unknown category is present in the database? You can use below query to getcategories.

> SELECT e.*, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS name FROM catalog_category_entity AS e INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS at_name_default ON (at_name_default.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_name_default.attribute_id = '41') LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS at_name ON (at_name.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_name.attribute_id = '41')

I hope it helps!